# get push notications which are lost

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing an app which uses GCM services. When network is not available, the GCM messages are not received. But when the network is available, the lost GCM messages are not getting received. Is any way to get the lost GCM messages?.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no way to get the list of undelivered messages. All you could do is to send message id from your device to the server to say message is received.